# horizontal scrollbars in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, fluid-layout, browser-scrollbars

I'm trying to build a fluid layout website based on the Golden Grid System without limiting IE7.

I am getting an unwanted horizontal scrollbar for the body. If I force the width to be smaller, it will disappear. However, it will not be fluid.

The layout looks fine, just some unwanted spacing to the right that I cannot account for which is causing the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is in header element. try adding `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->` . If you remove `display: block` or add `overflow: hidden` scrollbar disapear, but also design crashes.

Comment: I have included the Modernizr HTML5 Shim/IEPP. Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: check this out. #site-description font-style: italic causes this issue :) set width for it

Comment: for some reason, this only affects IE7, so I just targeted IE7 and applied `overflow: hidden`